# How to give device directly connected by wired ethernet a static ip?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I am connecting a raspberry pi directly to my laptop using a wired ethernet cable. I have set up the direct connection fine, and my pi can access the internet via my laptops wireless connection. Here's a command I copied and pasted from the internet to first verify the connection:

```
$ cat /var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases
1500971522 b8:27:eb:ce:e9:46 10.42.0.90 raspberrypi 01:b8:27:eb:ce:e9:46
```

In future it would be helpful to give my pi a static ip address of my choosing when I do this (since I will soon forget the above command). Can this be done, and if so, how? Also, which of the mac addresses outupt above is the pi's?

Comment: You can see the MAC addresses also with the command `ifconfig`. The network interface (`eth` for ethernet cable and `wlan` for wireless) will be shown near the MAC address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dnsmasq is very nice tool to setup DNS and DHCP Server for small LAN Networks. 
Using it you can also make reservation for IP address. I suggest you to read guide [here](https://carpie.net/articles/setting-up-a-home-network-dhcp-dns-server-with-dnsmasq).  In your case `b8:27:eb:ce:e9:46` is MAC of your raspberrypi device.

For reservation of Same IP in dnsmasq, Create new dnsmasq file.

```
sudo nano /etc/dnsmasq.d/example.dns
```

Write following content. Modify it as per requirement.

# General configuration

```
domain-needed bogus-priv 
domain=home.lan
dhcp-range=10.42.0.90,static,48h 
dhcp-option=10.42.0.1



 # Static IPs 
 dhcp-host=b8:27:eb:ce:e9:46,rasberrypi,10.42.0.90
```